# in jquery $.when(ajax).done(function(){do sth}, how can i callback twice to the same callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

In jquery I have the following code:

Part A:

```
$.when(result = $.startAsyncRequest(arg)).done(function(){
    console.log(result); // this should be called every time something is returned   
    if (result.hasOwnProperty("responseJSON")){
       console.log("build frontend table using completed task");
    }

});
```

Part B:

```
jQuery.extend({

   startAsyncRequest: function(arg){
       console.log(arg);
       $.when(result = makeAjaxRequest(arg)).done(function(){
           var taskid = result.taskid;
           var taskurl = "someurl" + taskid;
           startProgressBar(taskurl, {
           onSuccess: function(){
               $.when(result2 = makeAjaxRequest(taskid)).done(function(){
                  console.log("received completed task"); 
                  return result2;
               });
           });
           return "starting progress bar";
       });
       return "started task";
    }

});
```

Part A starts a function (Part B) that contains several ajax post requests, all of which are deferred. One of these requests is made based on a callback once a progress bar has completed.

Every time that startAsyncRequest returns, I would like it to return to Part A and log the result to the console. So I would expect it to return there several times, but it only returns once (the first request, "started task").

Is there a way to do this?

I don't want to break up startAsyncRequest into more than one function, as Part A is repeated a lot across my code, and I want it to wrap all of the task calling, progress bar and task retrieving logic in one function.

Comment: To call callback multiple times use progress & notify functions of deferred.

Comment: No, there is no way doing that with `$.when()`. Promises fulfill/reject only once, not multiple times. The easiest would be to pass a callback and just call that multiple times, at any point in your processing.

Comment: i would pass the callback as an argument to the request, or in the .done part?

Comment: Bergi's comment worked - I passed on a callback function to the request as an anonymous function, and got rid of the .done() part completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was -

Part A:

```
$.startAsyncRequest(arg, function(result){
    console.log(result); // this should be called every time something is returned   
    if (result.hasOwnProperty("responseJSON")){
       console.log("build frontend table using completed task");
    }

});
```

Part B:

```
jQuery.extend({

   startAsyncRequest: function(arg, callbackFct){
       console.log(arg);
       $.when(result = makeAjaxRequest(arg)).done(function(){
           var taskid = result.taskid;
           var taskurl = "someurl" + taskid;
           startProgressBar(taskurl, {
           onSuccess: function(){
               $.when(result2 = makeAjaxRequest(taskid)).done(function(){
                  console.log("received completed task"); 
                  callbackFct(result2);
               });
           });
           return callbackFct("starting progress bar");
       });
       return callbackFct("started task");
    }

});
```

Comment: looks like forged question  answer, to get points by yourself. look at my answer, jquery give it you out-of-box, you do not need re-invent it.

Answer (score -2):

Check this : https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

```
function wrap(ajaxRequest){
  var defer = $.Deferred();
  ajaxRequest.done(function(resp){
     defer.notify({ "message" : "Done Success", resp : resp })
  }).fail(function(resp){
     defer.notify({ "message" : "Error Failure", resp : resp });
  });
  setTimeout(function(){
     defer.notify({ "message" : "Request is made", resp : null });
  })
  return defer.promise();
}

/// Calling function


  wrap($.ajax({
   // params
  })).progress(function(obj){
     console.log(obj)
  })
```